# Sublime text add another caret on the line under

Tags: linux, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

What is the name of the command for adding another caret on the line below your current caret in sublime text.

This behavior is not working for me on linux, but I don't know the name of the command to search in the sublime keymap...

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

The command is `select_lines` which takes a boolean (true/false) arg called `forward` which if set to `true` adds a caret / cursor on the line below and if `false` adds one on the line above.

By default on Linux the command is mapped like this:

```
{ "keys": ["alt+shift+up"], "command": "select_lines", "args": {"forward": false} },
{ "keys": ["alt+shift+down"], "command": "select_lines", "args": {"forward": true} },
```

Personally I have the commands remapped to `alt+up` and `alt+down` because those keys are easier to press they are not mapped to anything at all, by default, on Linux which I also use.